# Перемещение к якорю

Tags: javascript

Как можно реализовать плавное перемещение к якорю, без участия сторонних библиотек? Получается реализовать только с верхней точки до нужной, ну если не с верху уже все не корректно, а снизу вверх вообще ума не приложу как сделать.

```
    var top = 0;
    var scr = setInterval(function () {
        top += 10;
        window.scrollTo(0, top);
        if(top > coords.top ){
            clearInterval(scr);
        }
    }, 15);
```

Comment: [window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) подскажет текущую позицию экрана. Алгоритм тривиальный. Не представляю с чем ещё может возникнуть проблема.

Comment: можно посмотреть в сторону функции [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: @Grundy если ее использовать, то как быть с анимацией?

Comment: @РоманФедоров, что имеется ввиду под анимацией в данном контексте?

Comment: @Grundy ну что бы постепенно спускалось, а не сразу, как показал выше использовал setInterval

Comment: в firefox работает `bahavior:'smooth'`

Comment: @Grundy только его смотрел, но только в firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто развитие вашего кода:

```
var myScroll = function(to){
    var currentScroll = window.scrollY,
        down = currentScroll < to; //вниз крутим или вверх

    var scr = setInterval(function () {
        currentScroll = currentScroll + 10 * (down ? 1 : -1);
        window.scrollTo(0, currentScroll);
        if((down && currentScroll > to) || (!down && currentScroll < to)){
            clearInterval(scr);
        }
    }, 15);
}
```

Использование: `myScroll(600)`.

Но я не считаю удачной идеей использовать здесь интервал и я бы вообще отталкивался от продолжительности анимации и рассчитывал кол-во шагов и их частоту.

Вместо setInterval я привык использовать более безопасный вариант

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //do something
    if(continue){
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 20);
    }
}, 20);
```

хотя в данном случае, признаюсь, разницы c setInterval не вижу.

Я обычно шел о другому пути при создании анимации: принимал аргументом длительность анимации, делил ее на длительность одного кадра (20мс, к примеру) и так же делил изменение анимируемого параметра. Таким образом вычислял на сколько нужно изменить один параметр и сколько итераций требуется.Выставлял таймеры по 20мс и производил в них изменения на вычисленную величину.

Полез  сейчас найти показательный код и нашел статью про создание анимации, которой раньше не встречал. На первый взгляд весьма интересно: https://learn.javascript.ru/js-animation

Comment: Спасибо, не плохо реализовано,  если не сложно то в двух словах как бы Вы лучше сделали, мб что то в голову придет.

Comment: @РоманФедоров дополнил ответ. может быть найдете что-то интересное.